# Downloading files with PHP - Only downloading one at a time!

Tags: php, download, header, readfile

I have a PHP file that serves up a file, but the problem is that no matter what browser is being used, if you click on 2 links that go to 2 separate files, the second download doesn't start until the first one is complete! Any ideas?

**Download Code**

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fullpath));
readfile($fullpath);
```

**Example Links**

- Link 1: download.php?downloadfile=1
- Link 2: download.php?downloadfile=2

Comment: You are sure that Apache is not limiting the number of concurrent connections? Some installations do that.

Comment: What OS is the server? Are you using apache? What do you max_concurrant_settings look like?

Comment: The server is a Linux server running Apache. Where can the max_concurrent_settings setting be found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There could be different reasons for this.

- You are using sessions. Therefor only one script at a time is allowed to modify the session. So download B can only start after download A has finished. Did you try two downloads concurrently with download A in browser A and download B in browser B? Check description for [session_write_close](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)
- Some other HTTP issue where your browser won't open multiple connections to the server but reuse a single connection and that way of course has to wait until first request finishes.
- Some OS/Webserver setting which only allows a very limited number of open concurrent connections either in total or per host

Comment: I've tried 2 browsers at the same time and that seems to be working fine. Really not sure what could be causing this as it's happening in Firefox & Safari.

Comment: @Bisbo .. i think the first point about session_write_close should solve ur problem .. i would suggest that you place that before u start sending the content of the file.

Comment: Ah brilliant! I used session_write_close() after I finished using the session and it's working perfectly! Thanks so much for your help! Was really bugging me :-)